# Xcode4.5: UITextField does not write

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextfield

In my App there is a textField that when you tap on it the keyBoard shows up as normally but when you tap the keys of the keyBoard it does not write, it keeps blank.
Why is this happening? I don't know what to do!
Thanks!

CODE

ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *myText;
}
```

In IB it is correctly linked.

Comment: I added the code, but I think it is not relevant because there is not so much code as you see...

Comment: You probably checked this link but If you did not yet here is a link with similar question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954405/how-do-i-type-using-my-keyboard-on-the-iphone-simulator

Comment: Did not work, I have no idea about what is happening with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! here: [Keyboard and cursor show, but I can't type inside UITextFields and UITextViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447875/keyboard-and-cursor-show-but-i-cant-type-inside-uitextfields-and-uitextviews)

In my opinion is one of the million bugs that iOS6 have, because It did not happen on iOS5.