# Sometime mac keyboard dosen't work i have to type from simulator keyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, keyboard, ios-simulator

I googled it and try many options but doesn't get success
i am working on two apps at a time so when i run one app. mac keyboard works but when i run another app it stop working.
i have to type from simulator keyboard i tried `Hardware>Keyboard>Connect Hardware Keyboard` but doesn't work 
and sometimes it work i am able to type from mac keyboard in same case. 
i am using xcode 9.2.
I also tried this question [Not able to type in textfield in iphone simulator using Mac Keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979510/not-able-to-type-in-textfield-in-iphone-simulator-using-mac-keyboard)
any help will appreciate

Answer (score 2):

If you delete the following file and restart Xcode it should work.

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist
```

Or you can try this:

1. Open `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist`
2. Set value for `CaptureKeyboardInput` to `YES`
3. Restart Simulator.

More info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47696048/413877

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me Xcode 9.3:

1. `Simulator app > Quit Simulator`
   [image]
2. Rerun app