# Xcode log "Writing analzed variants"

Tags: xcode, logging

Running Xcode 13 I see the following log when launching my iOS app in the Simulator:

> Writing analzed variants.

Note that this is, hopefully, a misspelling of the log:

> Writing anal**y**zed variants.

What is causing this log noise? Is something in my code triggering it?

How can I hide this "Writing analzed variants." Xcode log?

Comment: Wow, I never realized it was misspelled until today.

Comment: I hope and pray someone did that on purpose. Also, for those who feel the name of the planet Uranus is a problem, and aren't much impressed with Futurama's suggested new name Urectum, I think we can all agree that there cannot possibly be a better name for our distant fellow satellite than Analzed

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to Quinn “The Eskimo!” at Apple Developer Technical Support, this message is Xcode log noise and can be ignored.

An Apple [bug report](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) should be filed to help flag and silence the log.

- https://developers.apple.com/forums/thread/689066
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/115461

---

> It’s important to keep an eye on log messages and fix any obvious problems they call out. However, if you see a log message that’s not obviously your fault, it could just be **log noise**.
>
> There are two criteria you should apply here:
>
> - Is the log message associated with a specific failure? That is, when you see the log message, do you also see other problems?
> - Is the log message written in terms you understand? That is, does it reference APIs or data that you’re using?
>
> If the answer to both of these questions is “No”, it’s reasonable to conclude that the log message is just noise and you can ignore it. If you find it to be particularly irksome, file a [bug report](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) requesting that it be silenced.

Answer (score 1):

For me this issue warning coming because of keyboard was not working in my simulator, I have made some mistakes in my code in `SceneDelegate` for `window` initialisation, but once I have removed that line of code this message not showing in `log/consol`

**these 2 lines I have removed from SceneDelegate, these two lines created this issue for me**

```
let windowScene = UIWindowScene(session: session, connectionOptions: connectionOptions)
self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
```

So I have removed these from SceneDelegate

[for `SceneDelegate` Code and the keybaord issue see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70106883/7500742)

Answer (score 1):

This was annoying me because the log lines seemed to be causing a delay, which made my UI feel sluggish. I tried a number of ways to speed up my segue code before seeing the lines in the log and thinking they might be taking time.

I was using a custom keyboard which didn't have an equivalent in iOS, and I'd left "Use the Same Keyboard Language as macOS" selected in the Input > Keyboard menu. Turning that off got rid of the logging, and fixed the associated slowdown.