# iOS 15 crash when textfield calls becomeFirstResponder only for some devices - NSInvalidArgumentException -[NSConcreteValue properties]

Tags: crash, accessibility, textfield, ios15, becomefirstresponder

My app has this mysterious crash that I've been pulling my hairs out for couple of weeks now:

[image: Crash log]

It crashes when a textfield is tapped on and method becomeFirstResponder is called. It only crashes in a few iOS devices running iOS 15; other devices are working fine. My app is a document-based, multi scene app with Swift and Objective C mixed.

It crashes when the keyboard is pulled up and some accessibility key couldn't be found (according to the crash logs).

Anybody has same experience or could point me to a direction to resolve this crash, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I was commenting on another question trying to solve this same thing. However they found iOS 15.2 works for them now? Here is a link to the question, though I am not tagging this as a duplicate because I can not confirm it is solved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69595143/why-does-editing-a-textfield-throw-a-nsinvalidargumentexception?noredirect=1#comment124417518_69595143

Answer (score -1):

Try to go to your device Settings, and then search for Accessibility.
There you can find VoiceOver, Audio Descriptions, and Speak Selection.
Some of them can influence your app, like a few months ago I had a similar crash that was happening only to one user, but I was consistent to track it down so I've followed these steps I've just told you and managed to reproduce the crash and fix it. Let me know if this works for you.