# Xcode: iOS Simulator Dev Menu will not open

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

Specs: React Native, xCode, iOS Simulator

I'm currently running xCode and just trying to start my hello world however despite numerous approaches I cannot get the dev menu in the iOS Simulator to open. The hotkey **<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>** will not work.

I have tried:

1. I checked and unchecked the simulator keyboard settings, “Connect
   Hardware Keyboard”. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954405/how-do-i-type-using-my-keyboard-on-the-iphone-simulator)
2. I have tried “Reset Content and Settings” in the simulator menu.
3. Switching between scheme settings for the project. “Check your
   scheme settings. The current scheme shows at the top of Xcode. Click
   on it, then Edit Scheme. Under "Run", make sure the build
   configuration is set to Debug. If it's set to something different,
   you won't get the dev menu.” [Reference](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5122)
4. Restarting the simulator and restarting my mac.

Comment: Click on simulator, in application menu go: Hardware > Shake Gesture. Or SHIFT + CMD + Z, or CMD + DD (D two times). You can use CMD + R for reload. Make sure that Debug > Slow Animation is not checked!

Answer (score 13):

Let's you try `command + control + z`

Comment: This is a life saver, some times  command + D does not work!
This nails it.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and after searching a lot I finally got a solution.

Create a fresh project by react-native init  and see if it(dev menu) works or not? If it does, just upgrade the react-native version of your project. In my case, creating a fresh project worked.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when the default launch device as iPhone 11. But when I ran the command to run with iPhone 11 Pro developer menu came back. May be specific to a device on my machine.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-simulator-ios

"react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 11 Pro'"

To list all devices

```
xcrun simctl list devices
```